# load paragraph in graphql

Tags: paragraphs

i have a content type with "artist" and i have a paragraph type with "album" name. in album i have two field 1. name 2. release date.
i create a field with "field_album" name in "artist" content type that this field reference to paragraph. now i want write a query that show artist name and all albums with name and release date.
I create this query to load artist but i cant load paragraph.

```
    query{
  nodeQuery(filter: {conditions:[{field:"title",value: ["artistname"], operator: EQUAL}]}){
    count
    entities {
      ...on NodeArtist{
        nid
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

for load paragraph query must like this

```
query{
  nodeQuery(filter: {conditions:[{field:"title",value: ["artistname"], operator: EQUAL}]}){
    count
    entities {
      ...on NodeArtist{
        nid
        title
        fieldAlbum {
          entity{
            ... on ParagraphAlbum {
              fieldName
              fieldReleaseDate
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://github.com/drupal-graphql/graphql/issues/676#issuecomment-423912937